# Down Voting a feature request and locked features on META

Tags: discussion, down-votes

When I requested a feature here on this site, I got down-voted because the voters didn't like the request, and didn't think it was right. I don't think this is the appropriate behavior, and I will probably get down-voted on this to, but anyways, the tooltip says you must down-vote when the question is unclear, not useful, or does not show any research. I know you would say that a feature request that people don't like is not useful, but a not useful question is a duplicate, or is not answerable.

Rather make a feature voting for questions tagged as feature request.

If down-voting on this site is so *different*, why does it affect your reputation when you only made an innocent feature request?

I don't care about reputation; I care about the features that open with reputation. Because you make a "bad" suggestion does not mean that you are not allowed to down-vote and up-vote or chat.

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta, and is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Oh, and it's also worth noting that your one feature request is something that's been asked for a lot, so had you actually done research you'd have already known the answer to the question.  The downvotes were't (just) disagreement with the suggestion.

Comment: Also see [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) and *especially* [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: It should be noted that although meta voting can mean agreement/disagreement, your meta votes should not always be used for that. For example, support questions should be voted the same as any other question, based on usefulness, quality, and research effort. I have a meta post proposing the meta FAQ section on downvoting be clarified, because I see this frequently being confused as "meta votes are for agreement/disagreement", which is not always true. [Update the meta FAQ to clarify when meta voting should be different from regular voting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157124/158605)

Comment: Another demonstration of why [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites) should be implemented...

Comment: Please relax a bit.  You are only on meta for a day, and already have three (heavy downvoted) questions. Please have a look around and try to find out how this place works. It is different, sometimes hard, but you get used to it in the end.

Comment: @toonkrijhe I just try to ask questions, I was raised to not be scared of asking questions because if you dont know something you must have the freedom to ask... I am pretty cool, and dont care about downvotes or rep, i just care about an good awnser to my question, witch I got on all three downvoted posts

Comment: @lontgomjr: the problem with that is that just firing off a question without research first doesn't scale. We'd all be answering the same set of questions over and over again. Please do go ahead and research here first!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to get used to the idea downvoting on meta has a different meaning. Especially for feature requests this shows the support or disapproval for a given idea and does not necessarily reflect the quality of your post.

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: @lontgomjr reputation on meta is also different :) what I mean is that you should not take it personally and reputation here should not matter that much

Comment: The thing is that rep gives you more features on the site....

Comment: @lontgomjr: ...which aren't that important.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding rep, it's only meta rep. Big deal. The reason meta needs rep is because it is a meta for all the SE sites, not just SO. if the SO rep was carried over, then people who are active on other sites but not on SO will have a hard time participating here.

Regarding features that come with rep: Well, you have to live with that. Upvote suggestions you like. Comment on ones you don't like. Downvotes on meta only lose you the ability to create chat rooms on chat.mso (useless), and the ability to edit CW posts on MSO without approval (not that important, suggested edits get approved quickly). If you get massively downvoted, you may lose the ability to set bounties or comment, but this takes time.

A lot of the downvotes you have gotten are due to poor presentation. Take more effort in making your question presentable. Search meta and make sure it hasn't been asked already. If it looks like you don't care, we won't either.

If all your questions are getting downvoted, take some time, browse meta, and figure out how it works.